# How to use expressions in Power-Automate to transform data in Apply to each

Tags: power-automate

I have data in SharePoint that I want to automate a data transformation to Excel output.  There will be multiple rows and columns of data in the final flow. In the particular case that I am testing, I have a Boolean column, "Control?" that I want to transform from true/false to "Yes"/"No".

I am able to gather that data from SharePoint and write out sample rows to an Excel table:

[image: Power-Automate flow]

The column showing the Control? value:

```
item/LastName": "@items('Apply_to_each')?['Control_x003f_']
```

I would expect that I could use this expression:

```
if(equals(@items('Apply_to_each')?['Control_x003f_'], true), "Yes", "No")
```

This is invalid. So, I start by trying to build-up valid expressions.

```
equals(true, true)
```

Works

```
equals(@items('Apply_to_each')?['Control_x003f_'], true)
```

Invalid.  So I try to us the interface to insert Dynamic content in the expression

[image: inserting Dynamic content]

I select value, which give me the expression:

```
equals(outputs('Get_items')?['body/value'], true)
```

I replace 'body/value' with 'Control_x003f_'

```
equals(outputs('Get_items')?['Control_x003f_'], true)
```

This is valid, but always returns false, regardless of the value of the value of "Control?"

I am hoping for some direction, as I will have many, and more complex data transformations to perform.

Comment: Any chance you can share the json from the Get items response? Just a couple of items will be fine and just mask the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is the '@' character. Your formula should work without it:

```
if(equals(@items('Apply_to_each')?['Control_x003f_'], true), "Yes", "No")
```

When you are copy-pasting fields into formulas you have to make sure you delete the enclosing '@{}'.

Also, the reason why your last expression is not working, is that the output of 'Get items' is always an array, even if you apply filters to reduce it to 1 record. In the context of the array, your 'Control?' field does not make sense. However, since the expression includes a '?', it returns false instead of an error. Confusing, but it is actually a nice feature of PA imho.